# Cognito callback token to API GW Authorizer

Tags: amazon-web-services, postman, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

Is there a way to use a token passed to APIGW through a Cognito callback URL to authorize an APIGW call? Currently users go to `https://poolid.auth.region.amazoncognito.com/login?client_id=clientid&response_type=token&scope=email+openid+phone+profile&redirect_uri=$ApiGWInvokeUrl`
then after redirected to  `https://abc123.execute-api.region.amazonaws.com/dev#id_token=......&access_token=......&expires_in=3600&token_type=Bearer`

The token information works in testing Authorizer but the call returns "Missing Authentication Token". How can I change the API GW to take the token information from the redirect and pass it to the Cognito Authorizer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The URL fragments are not sent to the backend by your browser. Anything after the `#` in the URL (which includes the tokens) won't be sent to API Gateway.

Comment: Wouldn't URL Query String Parameters allow them to be processed?

Comment: They are formatted like query string parameters but they in fact are not. Inspect the url, every thing after the # is a url fragment and is not send to the backend.